# Symmetry argument in an integral

Tags: integration

I am facing the following problem. Consider the $N$-fold integral
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\cdots\int_0^{+\infty} \prod_{j=1}^{N+1}\left( e^{(x_j-x_{j-1})^2} - e^{(x_j+x_{j-1})^2} \right)dx_1 \cdots dx_N$$ 
(please forget the underlying problem, I am just interested on the algebraic side of this calculation, it is not a question related to analysis). It seems that up to some manipulations, this integrals can be rewritten as
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left( e^{\sum_{j=1}^{N+1}(x_j-x_{j-1})^2} - e^{\sum_{j=1}^{N+1}(x_j+x_{j-1})^2} \right)dx_1 \cdots dx_N.$$
Could you please help to understand how it works ? Thanks.

Comment: You probably want minus signs next to the exponents. Also possibly some factors of two? Not sure about that.

Comment: @Sharkos: Sorry, but I don't understand the comment. I checked what I've written, and I don't see a mistake.

Comment: I don't see how any amount of algebraic manipulation is going to get you from an integral from zero to an integral from $-\infty$.

Comment: My instinct is that the integral diverges unless you have $e^{-(\cdots)^2}$ throughout.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. This integral is very very simplified. There is a complex constant in each exponential and I dropped it for the sake of understandability. Please keep in mind this is not a question about integral existence.

Comment: @dfeuer: Well he allows a symmetry argument. However the signs seem to look wrong to me for that to work nicely...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough sketch of what I think is going on.  I'll pretend that there are minus signs in all the exponents, so that the integrals make sense; otherwise, the problem admits the trivial solution that one divergent integral is just as non-existent as another.

Starting with your original integral, imagine expanding the product of $N+1$ factors. You get $2^{N+1}$ terms, half with $+$ signs and half with $-$ signs.  Concentrate for the moment on just one of those terms.  It's a product of $N+1$ exponentials, which you can write as the exponential of a sum of $N+1$ terms, each of the form $(x_j\pm x_{j-1})^2$.  By suitably changing variables, changing some (suitably chosen) $x_j$'s to $-x_j$, you can make all the summands look like $(x_j-x_{j-1})^2$, or, if you prefer, you can make them all look like $(x_j+x_{j-1})^2$.  Do the former (resp. the latter) if the exponential you're working with had a positive (resp. negative) sign when you expanded the original product.  Now I'll describe what to do with the positive terms; the analog applies to the negative ones. The integrands in all the positive terms look like $\exp(\sum_j(x_j-x_{j-1})^2)$, but the range of the variables $x_j$ is different in different terms: If you changed variables from $x_j$ to $-x_j$, then the (new) $x_j$ ranges from $0$ to $-\infty$, and furthermore there's a minus sign arising from the change of variables. You can remove those minus signs by having those $x_j$'s range from $-\infty$ to $0$.  The other $x_j$'s, the ones you didn't change in the integral, still range from $0$ to $+\infty$.  So you end up with an integral over one orthant; some variables range from $0$ to $\infty$ and the rest range from $-\infty$ to $0$.  What needs to be checked now (and my omitting this check is one reason that this is only a sketch), is that these integrals over the various orthants fit together into just two integrals over the whole space $\mathbb R^N$, one for the positive integrands and one for the negative.  Those should give you the rewritten form in the question.